# Делаю змейку на c++ не получается ввод с русской раскладки

Tags: c++

```
void Input()
{
  if (kbhit())
  {
      char c=_getch();
      if (c=='w' || c=='ц') GolP=Pos::UP; else
      if (c=='s' || c=='ы') GolP=Pos::DOWN; else
      if (c=='d' || c=='в') GolP=Pos::RIGHT; else
      if (c=='a' || c=='ф') GolP=Pos::LEFT;
  }
}
```

P.S. Вот весь код :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

bool GameEnd = false;
enum Pos {DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT,UP};
int score=0;
int XvostX[100],XvostY[100],XvostT=0;

const int rows=20;
const int columns=20;
int GolX=rows/2-1;
int GolY=columns/2-1;
Pos GolP=Pos::UP;
int FruitX,FruitY;

void Draw()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
        {
            int otstup=0;
            for (int k=0; k<XvostT; k++) if (XvostX[k]==i && XvostY[k]==j) {cout << 'o'; otstup++;}
            if (GolX==i && GolY==j) {cout << 'O'; otstup++;}
            if (GolX==i && GolY==j && GolX==FruitX && GolY==FruitY) {} else if (FruitX==i && FruitY==j) {cout << '@'; otstup++; }
            if (j==0 || j==columns-1 || i==0 || i==rows-1) cout << '#';
            if (j==columns-1) cout << endl; else if (i!=0 && i!=rows-1 && otstup==0) cout << " ";
        }
    cout << "Счет:" << score;
    Sleep(200);
}

void Logic()
{
    if (GolX==0 || GolX==rows-1 || GolY==0 || GolY==columns-1) {GameEnd=true; return;}
    if (GolX==FruitX && GolY==FruitY)
        {
            XvostT++;
            FruitX=rand() % rows;
            FruitY=rand() % columns;
            while (FruitX==0 || FruitX==rows-1 || FruitY==0 || FruitY==columns-1) {FruitX=rand() % rows; FruitY=rand() % columns;}
            score++;
        }
    int PrX=XvostX[0];
    int PrY=XvostY[0];
    int Pr2X,Pr2Y;
    XvostX[0]=GolX;
    XvostY[0]=GolY;
    for (int i=1; i<XvostT; i++)
    {
        Pr2X=XvostX[i];
        Pr2Y=XvostY[i];
        XvostX[i]=PrX;
        XvostY[i]=PrY;
        PrX=Pr2X;
        PrY=Pr2Y;
    }
    if (GolP==Pos::UP) {GolX--;}
    if (GolP==Pos::DOWN) {GolX++;}
    if (GolP==Pos::LEFT) {GolY--;}
    if (GolP==Pos::RIGHT) {GolY++;}
    for (int i=0; i<XvostT; i++)
    {
        if (XvostX[i]==GolX && XvostY[i]==GolY) {GameEnd=true; return;}
    }
}

void Input()
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
        char c=_getch();
        if (c=='w' || c=='ц') GolP=Pos::UP; else
        if (c=='s' || c=='ы') GolP=Pos::DOWN; else
        if (c=='d' || c=='в') GolP=Pos::RIGHT; else
        if (c=='a' || c=='ф') GolP=Pos::LEFT;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    while (FruitX==0 || FruitX==rows-1 || FruitY==0 || FruitY==columns-1) {FruitX=rand() % rows; FruitY=rand() % columns;}
    while (!GameEnd)
    {
        Input();
        Logic();
        Draw();
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "Вы проиграли :( , ваш счёт : " << score;
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Видимо перепутаны кодировки. По-умолчанию пользовательский ввод конвертируется в CP866. А у вас в исходниках - что-то другое.

Comment: Я пишу на Code Block 20.03, и в коде я прописал setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian") для вывода на русском языке

Comment: Я про ввод вообще-то. setlocale для ввода-вывода на русском языке вообще не должен использоваться.